# How to use adaptor pattern in case?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class `PieClass` that accepts data `$data` and iterate this data by following schema:

```
public function setData($data) {
  foreach($data as $value) {
      $a[$value->id] = $value;
  }
}
```

So, it expects to get `$data` by the concrete format.

There is another class model is named as `ClassModel`. Using dependency injection it takes any model like:

```
class ClassModel {
   public $model;
   public function __constructor($model) {
     $this->model = $model;
   }

   public function data(){
      return $this->model->query("...")->get();
   }
}
```

So, as `getData()` get return different set of fields it should be prepared to use in `PieClass` class.

Therefore I try to create class `Adoptor` beetwen `ClassModel` and `PieClass`.

I have started to create interface:

```
interface IDataAdapter {
    public function data() {}
}
```

Then I created class:

```
class GraphPieWorkAdapter implements IDataAdapter {

    public function data() {

    }
}
```

Also class `ClassModel` must implement `IDataAdapter`:

```
class ClassModel implements IDataAdapter {
   public function data();
}
```

What to do next, how to utilize adopt pattern?